# Given that the number 20202021 can be written as the sum of two primes, find the (positive) difference of these two primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given that the number 20202021 can be written as the sum of two primes, find the (positive) difference of these two primes. Does anyone know how to solve this. I am trying to make a math team answer key and I am unsure how to solve this question

Comment: Is $20202019$ actually prime? If it is, then the difference would be $20202017$. On the other hand, if it is not, then $20202021$ could not, in fact, be written as the sum of two primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Since all primes are odd (except 2) and sum of 2 odd numbers is even.

This implies that , $20202021 = 2 + 20202019$ only.

So , positive difference is 20202017.

Comment: This answer would only be valid if $20202019$ were actually prime. If it were composite instead, then the question would become meaningless.